# What is the loading order for fixtures files in Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, fixtures

In my current project, I have multiple fixtures files. I would like to assign each files with data related to my tests.

ie:

- Articles has one Author
- Articles has many tags

Fixtures:

**test/fixtures/commonAuthor.yml**

```
    # Contains Common authors, with no particularities
    Author:
      Author1:
        name: Author1
```

**test/fixtures/commonTag.yml**

```
    # Contains Common tags, with no particularities
    Tag:
      Tag1:
        name: Tag1
      Tag2:
        name: Tag2
```

**test/fixtures/test_Article.yml**

```
    # Contains All the data that is used by my functionals and unit tests
    Tag:
      Tag_not_active:
        name: Tag not active
    Article:
      Article_1:
        title:  Article 1
        Tags:   [Tag1, Tag2]
        Author: Author1
      Article_with_tag_innactive:
        title:  Article 2
        Tags:   [Tag1, Tag2, Tag_not_active]
        Author: Author1
```

I wonder if the files are loaded alphabetically, or in any other order.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using doctrine, the dependencies between fixtures are detected automatically and they will be loaded in order to fulfill all of them.

If you're using propel, the files are loaded in alphabetical order.

Comment: With Doctrine at least, this is not true in all cases. I *think* it fails when the fixtures are not all contained in the same fixtures folder, otherwise fine. And you can also force the loading order by pre-fixing fixture files with numbers (e.g. 1_file.yml, 2_file.yml, etc).